# Why does SetWinEventHook with EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE trigger on mouse movement?

Tags: c#

I created a hook on a process to register when its Window moves.
I use the event constant EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE, which per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> An object has changed location, shape, or size. The system sends this event for the following user interface elements: caret and window objects. Server applications send this event for their accessible objects.

And it works, but it also triggers on simple mouse over of the application. Can anyone explain why?

Here is an example to reproduce it:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern System.IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, System.IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

        public delegate void WinEventDelegate(System.IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, System.IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0x0000;
        private const uint EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE = 0x800B;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int processId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

            NativeMethods.SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE, EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE, System.IntPtr.Zero, WinEventProc, (uint)processId, (uint)0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
        }

        private void WinEventProc(System.IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, System.IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
        {
           if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Mouse moved");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Location changed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I *suspect* that this has something to do with Winforms generating the MouseEnter/Leave events.  Or it implementing an accessibility server automatically.  Hard to narrow down, this can't be turned off easily.  Just ignore the callback, you want to filter by idObject == OBJID_CURSOR.

Comment: I can confirm that I also see the callback for when the mouse cursor moves - and not just for Winforms apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header file `WinUser.h` has this to say about `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE`:

```
 * Note also that USER will generate LOCATIONCHANGE notifications for two
 * non-window sys objects:
 *      (1) System caret
 *      (2) Cursor
```

This explains why the event fires when the cursor moves.

As Hans says in his comment, just filter the object ID by `OBJID_CURSOR`.